# C# Reading Text File between two unique Chars

Tags: c#, streamreader

my text file looks like the following

```
things


stuff
more stuff


//xxxxxxxxxxx

these
are the lines
I want to read 
into a string

//yyyyyyyyyy
```

How can I read the lines between "//xxxxxxxxxxx" and "//yyyyyyyyyy"
into a string? also, I will not know what line number it is on; it will change from file to file, as well as how many lines are between those 2 delimiters.

I've figured out how to read the whole file, or how to read certain lines, but not how to just capture a block such as this. I do not want to read the entire file into a string first if that can be avoided. **I only want to read the lines between the 2 token into a string.**

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following:

Read each line using `String s = StringReader.ReadLine()`.
If s is not equal to the start read-block token ("//xxxxxxxxxxx"), then ignore it.
Otherwise, start a while loop, and keep reading each line until you see a line that equals your end read-block token ("//yyyyyyyyyy"), and save each line you read into a StringBuilder or just a String.

Here's the code:

```
        string start_token = "//xxxxxxxxxxx";
        string end_token = "//yyyyyyyyyy";
        String line;
        String text = [your text here];
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);
        while (!(line = reader.ReadLine()).Equals(start_token)) 
        { 
            //ignore
        } 
        String result = "";
        while (!(line = reader.ReadLine()).Equals(end_token)) 
        {
            result += line;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Came here to help, but this answer is 100% complete